# Grouping php array items based on user and created time

Tags: php, algorithm, arrays, grouping

This is an array of objects showing a user uploading photos:

```
Array
(
    [12] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => photo
            [created] => 2010-05-14 23:36:41
            [user] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 760
                    [username] => mrsmith
                )

            [photo] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 4181
                )

        )

    [44] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => photo
            [created] => 2010-05-14 23:37:15
            [user] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 760
                    [username] => mrsmith
                )

            [photo] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 4180
                )

        )
)
```

However instead of showing:

- mr smith uploaded one photo
- mr smith uploaded one photo

I'd like to display:

- mr smith uploaded two photos

by grouping similar items, grouping by user ID and them having added them within, let's say 15 minutes of each other. So I'd like to get the array in this sort of shape:

```
Array
(
    [12] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => photo
            [created] => 2010-05-14 23:36:41
            [user] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 760
                    [username] => mrsmith
                )

            [photos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                          (
                           [id] => 4181
                          )

                     [1] => stdClass Object
                          (
                           [id] => 4180
                          )
                )

        )
)
```

preserving the first item of the group and it's created time, and supplementing it with any other groupable photos and then unsetting any items that were grouped (so the final array doesn't have key 44 anymore as it was grouped in with 12).

The array contains other actions than just photos, hence the original keys of 12 and 44. I just can't figure out a way to do this efficiently. I used to use MySQL and PHP to do this but am trying to just use pure PHP for caching reasons.

Can anyone shed any insights? I thought about going through each item and seeing if I can group it with the previous one in the array but the previous one might not necessarily be relevant or even a photo. I've got total brain freeze :(

Comment: Is this data you're getting from a database?  If so, it is very inefficient to load entire tables into an array.  Perhaps you could clarify the application further?

Comment: I agree with Jonah.  Have you considered simply caching the result of the MySQL query?  Two birds, one stone and all that.

Comment: It's a users activity stream, akin to facebook stream. It used to grab activity from separate tables and combine into one unified array of objects. Of course this was quite inefficient and I couldn't use LIMIT.

So I was going to move everything to an activity table, where I can query activity very quickly and in one single query. The problem with that is, I can't then use MySQL to group photos together anymore as I'd done before. Like this:

 id user_id object_id type created

 1 2 48592  photo 18:18:50
 2 2 48593  photo 18:18:51
 3 2 548592  comment 18:18:55
 4 2 48594  photo 18:18:59

Comment: This is just my opinion, but I *think* you're causing a lot of extra work for yourself as well as setting yourself up for scalability problems down the road.  If it were me, again, my opinion, I'd stick with MySQL and the normalized tables, get your app up and running, and begin to focus on performance improvements, query tuning, etc, *after* figuring out where bottlenecks might be with something like xdebug. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, that's why I'm faced with this problem though, I'd started off with the normalised tables and with the app getting more attention it was causing frequent downtime with the server. The problem were these queries and the memory usage all on one page hit, and with users and search engines the server was struggling.

Running some benchmarks with the de-normalized "activity" table, an idea I'd got from questions here, while it does create more headaches, indicated it was much much faster and less memory intensive.

Comment: @Jim - Ah, well then, you're way ahead of me. That's what I get for making assumptions ;)  Wish I could actually help.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I'll give the answer a go but I think my brain has given up for the day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the entries are ordered by date you can do the following:

- Keep an array (let's call it `$foo`) with all the photos in a 15 minute window. Use the array as a FIFO list (use `array_shift` to remove items and `$foo[] = ...` to add).
- Iterate over the original array

  - Check the date of the current item and remove from the beginning of `$foo` all the entries whose date is more than 15 minutes less than the current item. Once you find an item that for something that happened less than 15 minutes ago, you can stop (it's a one line for loop).
  - Iterate over the the entries in `$foo`
  - If a photo by the same person is found, then

    - Alter the reference stored in `$foo` so that the new data is added
    - Remove the current item from the original array
    - break from inner loop
  - If not

    - Add a reference to the current item to the end `$foo` with `$foo = &$var`.

You may then reindex the original array with [array_values](http://www.php.net/array_values) to fill the gaps.